# match whole sentence with regex

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm trying to match sentences without capital letters with regex in Java:

```
"Hi this is a test" -> Shouldn't match
"hi thiS is a test" -> Shouldn't match
"hi this is a test" -> Should match
```

I've tried the following regex, but it also matches my second example ("hi, thiS is a test").

```
[a-z]+
```

It seems like it's only looking at the first word of the sentence.

Any help?

Comment: Don't use regex for that.

Comment: if a == a.toLowerCase()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-z]+` will match if your string contains any lowercase letter.

If you want to make sure your string doesn't contain uppercase letters, you could use a negative character class: `^[^A-Z]+$`

Be aware that this won't handle accentuated characters (like É) though.

To make this work, you can use Unicode properties: `^\P{Lu}+$`
`\P` means *is not in Unicode category*, and `Lu` is the *uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant* category.

Comment: This will include all sort of characters from Unicode: Chinese, Cyrillic, Arabic, other Latin uppercase characters, and who know what.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-z ]+$
```

Try this.This will validate the right ones.

Answer (score 1):

It's not matching because you haven't used a space in the match pattern, so your regex is only matching whole words with no spaces.

try something like `^[a-z ]+$` instead (notice the space is the square brackets) you can also use `\s` which is shorthand for 'whitespace characters' but this can also include things like line feeds and carriage returns so just be aware.

This pattern does the following:

`^` matches the start of a string

`[a-z ]+` matches any a-z character or a space, where 1 or more exists.

`$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually advise against regex in this case, since you don't seem to employ extended characters.

Instead try to test as following:

```
myString.equals(myString.toLowerCase());
```